# Div Not Being Hidden by Display: None;

Tags: html, media-queries, displaytag

I am trying to get my red sidebar divs to disappear when viewed on a mobile platform. I have the media queries coded, but they simply move to the bottom of the page rather than disappear. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am not allowed to use javascript on this project by the way. Thanks!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cn161gxf/)

```css
    html, body {
     background-color:#333;
     font-family:Helvetica;
     height:100%;
    }
    #column-left {
     float: left; 
     width: 15%; 
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#F00;
     }
    #column-right {
     float: right; 
     width: 15%; 
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#F00;
     }
    #column-center {
     display: inline-block; 
     width: 70%; 
     text-align:center;
     }
    .banner {
     width: 100%;
     background-color:#000;
    }
    #logo {
     width:10%;
    }
    nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
    text-align:center;
    }
    nav ul {
    display: table-row;
    list-style:none;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    }
    nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    }
    ul.menu a {
    font-size: 85%;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 25px;
    background:#000;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    border:1px solid white;
    }
    ul.menu a:hover {
     background-color: #FFF;
     color: #F00;
     border:1px solid black;
    }
    .image {
     border:2px solid black;
     border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
     padding: 5px 5px;
     margin-top:2%;
     margin-bottom:2%;
     background-color:white;
    }
    .heading {
     font-size:24px;
     text-shadow:0px 0px 10px #FFF;
    }
    .info {
     background-color:#FFF;
     border:2px solid black;
     border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
     padding: 10px 10px;
     width: 75%;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
     #pagewrap {
      width: 94%;
     }
     #content {
      width: 65%;
     }
     #navMenu {
      width: 100%;
     }
     .sidebar {
      width: 15%;
     }
     .image {
      width: 75%;
     }
     #column-left !important{
      float:none;
      display: none;
     }
     #column-right !important{
      float:none;
      display: none;
     }
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     body {
      background-color: #333;
     }
     #header {
      height: auto;
     }
     .heading {
      font-size: 24px;
      color: white;
     }
     #logo {
      width: 40%;
     }
     #column-left !important{
      float:none;
      display: none;
     }
     #column-right !important{
      float:none;
      display: none;
     }
     #column-center {
      width:100%;
     }
     nav {
      max-width:100%;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="banner">
    <center><a href="#"><img src="../Week 1/Logo/Logo.png" id="logo" /></a></center>
    </div>
    <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contest</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coupons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="column-center">
       <center><img src="../Week 1/Images/Product/plexusinuse.png" width="40%" id="main" /></center>
       <center><h1 class="heading">PlexiMax</h1></center>
       <p class="info">PlexiMax is an aerosol based cleaner, specialized for use on plexiglass. PlexiMax lifts dirt and grime from the surface allowing it to be wiped away with ease. While it is suggested that a microfiber cloth is used with the product, simple paper towels will provide great results.</p>
       <center><h1 class="heading">About Us</h1></center>
       <p class="info">This webpage is devoted to the materials used to clean everything you may own with an engine. Whether it be a car, a boat, or a plane you will find everything you need to clean it here. We have brushes, soaps, even pressure washers. While we started selling our PlexiMax plexiglass cleaner, we have since branched off to sell many different cleaning solutions. PlexiMax is still our most popular product, but the convenience of finding everything you need here has changed the entire dynamic of our site. We hope you find everything you need and use our products to find that new vehicle shine.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="column-left">
       <center><img src="../Week 1/Images/Other Products/brush.png" width="75%" class="image"/></center>
       <br />
       <center><img src="../Week 1/Images/Other 
    Products/carwashglove.png" width="75%" class="image" /></center>
       <br />
       <center><img src="../Week 1/Images/Other Products/carwashsoap.png" width="75%" class="image" /></center>
       </div>
      <div id="column-right">
       <center><img src="../Week 1/Images/Other Products/microfibercloths.png" width="75%" class="image"/></center>
       <br />
       <center><img src="../Week 1/Images/Other Products/pressurewasher.png" width="75%" class="image" /></center>
       <br />
       <center><img src="../Week 1/Images/Other Products/wax.png" width="75%" class="image" /></center>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you please add a JSFiddle?

Comment: That should work. I haven't uploaded this, I've just been checking it locally so the images are not included. The placeholders are there, but it honestly shouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS styles were invalid, that's because:

1. You need to use `!important` for seperate properties at the end of declaration.
2. You forgot (or just didn't) closed curly bracket in the media query sections.

So basically, your CSS styles were invalid:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    #pagewrap {
        width: 94%;
    }
    #content {
        width: 65%;
    }
    #navMenu {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 15%;
    }
    .image {
        width: 75%;
    }
    #column-left {
        float:none;
        display: none;
    }
    #column-right {
        float:none;
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: #333;
    }
    #header {
        height: auto;
    }
    .heading {
        font-size: 24px;
        color: white;
    }
    #logo {
        width: 40%;
    }
    #column-left {
        float:none;
        display: none;
    }
    #column-right {
        float:none;
        display: none;
    }
    #column-center {
        width:100%;
    }
    nav {
        max-width:100%;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/volter9/cn161gxf/1/

P.S.: next time you can try use CSS validator first: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: I don't know why I missed that, but it did the trick! I need to stop coding my websites late into the night haha. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a pretty simple issue: your `!important`s are in the wrong place:

http://jsfiddle.net/cn161gxf/3/

`!important` applies to individual properties, not elements.

Instead of:

```
#column-left !important{
    float:none;
    display: none;
}
#column-right !important{
    float:none;
    display: none;
}
```

Try:

```
#column-left{
    float:none !important;
    display: none !important;
}
#column-right{
    float:none !important;
    display: none !important;
}
```

****Disclaimer: DO NOT USE `!important`** unless you absolutely must. Using lots of `!important` styles will make maintenance harder, because you break the natural cascading in your stylesheets.

Comment: !important!  Try not to use `!important` if you can.  It's WAY overused, and will cause lots of problems later . . .

Comment: @Godisgood COMPLETELY AGREED! I was considering removing my answer because it looks like I am a proponent of using `!important`, which I am not. However, on the off-chance, someone might *need* to use `!important` but doesn't know how to do so correctly...

Comment: It's a fine answer, just trying to make that clear.  +1 for making it clear that `!important` is NOT a good habit to get into.  What a mess I've made of it before.

Comment: @Godisgood I added a disclaimer at the bottom to further clarify my position on the use of `!important`.

Comment: I understood that !important was kind of a risky thing to use. I saw it used on another possible solution so I tried it out, but come to find out I saw an example with it used in the wrong place. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: If you have selectors priority problems (when basically several styles override themselves not as you expected) try to specify much specific selector. More info about specifity (and !important): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity